# CORS error when trying to submit AMP form to Azure Logic app

Tags: cors, amp-html, azure-logic-apps

I have a simple AMP web page with a form I would like to submit to an Azure Logic App. I am loading

`<script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>`

in my HTML head so I can use AMPs built in form validation.

However, when I submit the form I get the following error...

```
Access to fetch at 'https://prod-logic-app-url' from origin 'https://www.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
```

<strike>There are no settings I can find within Azure Logic Apps related to CORS and I don't know how to send modified or additional headers from AMP forms.</strike>

Update. I've figured out how to set response headers from my logic app but i'm getting exactly the same error

[image]

Comment: How preflight request/response headers look like? Valid origin value includes also protocol (`https://` in your case), not just domain.

Answer (score 0):

This issue just came up when attempting to convert the WordPress Jetpack plugin's MailChimp module to be AMP compatible.

On the original non-AMP page, the form submission results in this `fetchSubscription()` function being [called](https://github.com/Automattic/jetpack/blob/8782a170fedf2c4ebc3943ecdb9b685d7af2c19d/extensions/blocks/mailchimp/view.js#L13-L33):

An XHR is opened to `https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/…` and WordPress.com REST API includes the response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

So, add two more response headers as below:

```
AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin: https://example.com
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin
```

For more details, you could refer to this [issue](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/10523#issuecomment-501775759).

Comment: How can I add these response headers from a Logic app?

Comment: After further experimenting I’m now convinced that Logic Apps don’t support CORS natively . I’m going to create a function app as they do support CORS and proxy the call through to the Logic App. Will post back with results (after I’ve got some sleep)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get this to work was to create an Azure function app. I set up CORS on the function app and then proxy through to the Logic app.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well. Postman worked (gave a 204), but browsers did not.

Edge had the most helpful error message: I was setting `credentials: 'include'` in my **request**, to work around some cross-origin cookie issues with my developer environment. But when this flag is on, **CORS cannot use a wildcard (*)**. And the CORS response from Azure Logic Apps does use a wildcard.

The solution for me was to stop using `credentials: 'include'` in my `fetch()` call.